# Cypress + CircleCI - How do I set the chrome browser version in the "orb"?

Tags: cypress, circleci

I'm trying to run cypress on CircleCI, but I can't find any good guides on how the "orb" works other than this: https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/cypress-io/cypress

In my config.yml file, this is the only configuration that I can get to work on CircleCI

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          executor: cypress/browsers-chrome69
          browser: chrome
```

This runs all the tests, and that's basically all I need. However, I think it's running on chrome version 69, which is really old. When I try to make it any other version of chrome, the executor is not recognized.

How do I set the chrome browser version?

Also, it would be nice to have more control over which tests to run, rather than simply run them all. How do I do that?

Any references to good guides for cypress + circleci would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the list of prebuilt containers here and replace `executor` with one of the options in the "Base Image" column https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/tree/master/browsers#cypressbrowsers

In addition, refer to the [circle.yml](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/.circleci/config.yml) in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/) for a reference of how the executor is composed.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to have these orbs point to the latest major release of Chrome?